# How to get SelectItem description in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have a selectItem that contains label,value and description.

```
  SelectItem item1 = new SelectItem();
    item1.setLabel("Code1");
    item1.setValue("Code1");
    item1.setDescription("This is the place to display actual Long discription for Code1");
```

I want to show the description value as a hover text in jsf page.

```
var oprions  = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
  for (var optIndex in oprions){
      options[optIndex].title = options[optIndex].description;
      alert("value is : " + options[optIndex].title);
  }
```

I have tried it as above, but i am getting 'undefined', if i place text instead of descrption i am getting the label value. But i want to display description.
Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Check your resultant html. If you are trying to use it in p:selectOneMenu or other elements used for selecting, you have something like this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu>
  <f:selectItem value="#{seedvarManagedBean.item1}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

which generates:

```
<div id="seedvar_form:j_idt15_panel" class="ui-selectonemenu-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-helper-hidden ui-shadow" style="width: 225px; z-index: 1003; display: block; top: 409.078125px; left: 412.59375px;">
  <div class="ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper" style="height:auto">
    <ul class="ui-selectonemenu-items ui-selectonemenu-list ui-widget-content ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-helper-reset">
      <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight" data-label="Code1" title="This is the place to display actual Long discription for Code1">Code1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

and you can get what you want from `li` element. Sry for my english.

If you have plain html select element, check your typo. You have define variable `oprions`, but in loop trying to use `options`